# Different android asset pack for each product flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-assetpacks

I want different product flavors of an android app to have their own asset packs (or possibly none at all). Tried something like

```
android {
   productFlavors {
       one {
          assetPacks[":pack1"]
       }
       two {
          assetPacks[":pack2"]
       }
       three {
       }
   }
}
```

but this just uses the last line encountered for all flavors, so that all of them include `pack2`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I have found solution which suits my needs (I guess it's not elegant but it works), maybe you can also use this @KasperPeeters. Because we build applications using script and we invoke build commands per build variant I decided to use Gradle command line param which controls if assets should be included in aab or not (you should be able to easily modify it to control which assets should be included). Then in `build.gradle` of app module I have a check:

`if (project.hasProperty("includeAssets")) { assetPacks = [":<you_asset_name>"] }`

and to build aab with assets I invoke command
`./gradlew :app:bundle[Variant] -PincludeAssets`

---

I am looking for something similar. My discovery so far is that assets files are always included in generated aab file. If you want to control which flavors will download the file when installed on the device you have to use delivery type other than `install-time`. I'll give `on-demand` a try and update topic if this works.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how this condition could be added based on the flavor?
I also have to use different asset packs for each flavor but I'm still not sure how to handle that! :(